# CSS animation delay (img display time)

Tags: html, css, slideshow

I've got this CSS:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes sliderFadeInOut {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 17% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 25% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 92% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:1;
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes sliderFadeInOut {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 17% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 25% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 92% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:1;
 }
}

@-o-keyframes sliderFadeInOut {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 17% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 25% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 92% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:1;
 }
}

@keyframes sliderFadeInOut {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 17% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 25% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 92% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:1;
 }
}

#slider {
background-size: cover;
position: fixed;
top: 100px;
bottom: 0px;
height:calc(100%-135px);
width: 100%;
}
#slider img {
border: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
margin: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position:absolute;
left:0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  
}

#slider img {
  -webkit-animation-name: sliderFadeInOut;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;

  -moz-animation-name: sliderFadeInOut;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-duration: 8s;

  -o-animation-name: sliderFadeInOut;
  -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-duration: 8s;

  animation-name: sliderFadeInOut;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 8s;
}
#slider img:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -o-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
#slider img:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 4s;
  -o-animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
#slider img:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 2s;
  -o-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
#slider img:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0;
  -o-animation-delay: 0;
  animation-delay: 0;
}
```

I'm learning CSS Animations, but I didn't find out how to set the display time of one image.

I tried to change the animation delay but that only causes trouble..

Do you have an idea how to do this ?

Best regards

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a047fs33/ this is a part. I want to display the images longer than just one or two secounds.

Comment: That makes sense. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were several things that needed some attention. Here's how I accomplished it, though there are other ways.

For the animation itself:

```
@keyframes sliderFadeInOut {
 0% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 17% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 25% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 92% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:0;
 }
}
```

This causes the image to fade in, then fade out at whatever `animation-duration` we set.

Set the `animation-iteration-count` to 1, so the animation runs once.

```
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
```

Each image in the stack needs to be timed to appear, then disappear as the next image in the stack becomes visible. To do this, use `animation-delay` and increase it for each image in the stack.

```
#slider img:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
#slider img:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
  opacity:0;
}
#slider img:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 8s;
   opacity:0;
}

#slider img:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 12s;
  opacity:0;
}
```

The staggered `animation-delay` properties cause the first image in the stack to be shown initially. It's animation takes 5 seconds and results in the image disappearing. At 4 seconds, the 2nd image in the stack starts it's animation, appearing just as the first image is disappearing. And then so on for the 3rd and 4th images.

In the code above there's also an initial `opacity` property for the 2nd, 3rd and 4th images. This is necessary to hide them initially.

As it's setup now the images will loop only once. Some minor tweaking to `animation-delay` and `animation-iteration-count` would cause it to loop infinitely.

Here's the working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/1ywagmmy/).